# Why does outliner show a different object selected

Tags: interface, outliner

Is there a reason that the object selected in the viewport is not the object shown as selected in the outliner?

Comment: Did you mean the **active** one and **selected** one? They could be different status at the same time

Comment: No. Suppose you have only one object selected.

Comment: Can you put the outliner image and your 3D View for it? It's a little bit unclear what the actual problem you encountered

Comment: Are you sure you only have one object selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know it was intended, where in Maya it always sync, but I know there is a good reason to make it unsync, I've read about it like sometimes ago but forgot what it is, but make it unsync can be confusing sometimes. 
So there is a Gsoc branch for outliner which has an options to make it sync or unsync mode between outliner and viewport, it is not in the master just yet, but let's hope it will eventually at the end.
See the discussion here :

https://devtalk.blender.org/t/gsoc-2019-outliner-weekly-reports/7642/7

https://devtalk.blender.org/t/gsoc-2019-outliner-branch-testing/7616/63